# Toyota Raum Radio memory loss

Tags: toyota, troubleshooting, audio

Can you help me Unlock Toyota Raum 2003 Radio to its normal state?
My battery ran flat, resetting my radio. I am getting some method on the internet about pressing the tuning Up and 1 buttons, but there is no 1 button on the new design Raums.

Comment: You may need a reset code specific to your vehicle. Check the glove box and owner's manual.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  You can click on the link to take a tour of the site to see how it works.  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour  Thank you for your question/contribution.  Hope to see you around.  Cheers!

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To unlock the stereo, the 4-digit reset code is required. [Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7543138_reset-code-toyota-factory-stereo.html) is the procedure to access the code entry screen.

If you don't have the code, you have 3 attempts to guess it (.33% chance, good luck). After the 3 attempts, the owner of the car will have to take it to a Toyota dealership with proof of ownership and valid identification to gain access.